# Let $f,g$ $\in$ G ($f$ and $g$ are elements of a group G). $fg$ and $gf$ must be in the same class of conjugates, even if the group is non-abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My classes on introductory group theory are centered around Tinkham's *Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics*. I was attempting to solve one of the problems in that textbook when I saw the exercise present in the title of this question in Zee's *Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists*. Formally, the exercise is as follows:

> Given two group elements $f$ and $g$, show that, while in general $fg \not= gf$, $fg$ is in the same class of conjugates as $gf$.

By *conjugate elements*, consider the definition present in most abstract algebra textbooks, i.e. $B = X^{-1}AX$ means that the element B of a group is conjugate to element A of the same group.

### My attempt at solving the problem

Let $G$ be a group and $A,B,X,Y,Z$ some of its elements. Let $E$ denote the group's identity element. If $AB \sim BA$, then there must exist $Z \in G$ such that

$$ Z^{-1}(AB)Z=BA $$

First, by taking some element $X$, a conjugate to $AB$ can be calculated in the following manner:

$$ X^{-1}(AB)X = X^{-1}(AEB)X = X^{-1}A(XX^{-1})BX=(X^{-1}AX)(X^{-1}BX) \ \ \ (1)$$

Which means that a conjugate to $AB$ is the product between two respective conjugates of $A$ and $B$ with respect to the same element $X$. If we were to calculate the conjugate of $BA$ with respect to some element $Y$, then we would obtain

$$Y^{-1}(BA)Y = (Y^{-1}BY)(Y^{-1}AY) \ \ \ (2)$$

I believe the problem would be solved if I could prove that $(1) \sim (2)$ for specific $X,Y$, but I'm not sure on how I can proceed. Perhaps my intuition is not on the right path. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You just need to show that $fg$ is conjugate to $gf$. You can multiply $fg$ on the left by $g$ and on the right by $g^{-1}$ to obtain $g(fg)g^{-1}=gf$. Hence $fg$ and $gf$ are in the same conjugacy class.

Comment: The conjugacy class of an element $a$ in a group $G$ is just the collection of all elements in $G$ that are conjugate to $a$. And two elements belong to the same conjugacy class if and only if one is conjugate to the other.

Comment: Excellent, that's pretty simple and straight forward. Concerning the second comment, I tried to use just that to try to find X and Y such that Z is possible. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $fg$ and $gf$ are in the same conjugacy class, because $gf=f^{-1}(fg)f$.